# When declaring two of the same CSS properties in one rule set, does the browser render both?

Tags: css, browser

When using the same CSS property in one rule set, in the case of needing to provide a fallback for browsers that don't support a property you may be using, like so:

```
body{
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgba(255, 255 ,255, 0.5);
}
```

Do browsers that understand both of these declarations render the first, then overwrite it with the second? Or does a browser save itself the hassle and only render the latter?

Edit: I am aware that if a browser understands both declarations it will render the latter, but I want to know if the browser renders/draws the first into the viewport and then overwrites it with the second or does a browser work in a way that means it only renders the one declaration that is required, potentially saving itself resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect modern (and probably old) browsers to parse the CSS rules supplied to it before rendering anything. Here's a screenshot from the Chrome profiler for both rules:

[image]

And here's another, for only the first rule:

[image]

As you can see, there are no extra steps involved when two different rules are present. If the browser was to render it twice, you would see another "Paint". (The slight reduction in paint time for the single rule is likely to be because I removed the `rgba` rule, so the browser did not have to take transparency into account).

Comment: Thanks. I agree with this, it makes sense that the browser only paints once.

Answer (score 1):

the last of the 2 will be applied

To be more precise: the first will be applied, then the second.
It would be the same as having 2 identical selectors setting the background property.
The one most descriptive will be applied. If they are the same, the last declared will be the one applied.

Comment: The question asks whether or not the browser will render the first, then overwrite it with the second. The OP knows that the 2nd rule is the one that gets applied.

Comment: I am aware of importance and specificity but what I am really getting at here is this: does a browser that understands both declarations, render them both (overwriting one with the other), or is a browser sophisticated enough to know only to render one (potentially saving resources)?

Answer (score 0):

The "C" in CSS stands for Cascading which means styles can add to or supercede preceding CSS rules.  So the second declaration will override the first.

Answer (score 0):

Browser handle this correctly. You can use that kind of rules.

For example, chrome will apply rgba, and IE8 will apply rgb.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers in general apply the following algorithm:

```
for each element in the DOM tree
    for each CSS rule
        if rule's selector matches element
            apply all declarations in rule
render
```

This is **not** how it works:

```
for each CSS rule
    for each element in DOM tree
        if rule's selector matches element
            for each declaration in rule
                apply declaration
                render
```

That would be a huge performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the basic [UA conformance requirements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#conformance) that browsers must first parse *all* CSS rules, then decide, by the principles set in the specifications, what values shall be used for each property of each element. There is no allowance for “incremental rendering” in the sense of applying part of the CSS code before reading the rest. And it would be very odd for a browser to deviate from this, as it would mean more work to implementors, more complaints from authors and end users, and no benefits.